# Simple non-asymptotic upper-bound for packing number of a hamming cube

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, coding-theory, packing-and-covering, sphere-packing

Looking for a simple upper-bound for the packing number of hamming cube, I'm led to consider the following. Fix $p \in (0,1/2]$. For a positive integer $n$, define $S_n(p) := \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor np\rfloor}{n\choose i}$,  and $M_n(p) := 1-\dfrac{1}{n}\log_2S_n(p)$. Note that $B_n(p):=2^n/S_n(p)$ is a well-known $np$-packing number of $\{0,1\}^n$. For example, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/283202/78539.

I've empirically observed that

> **Empirical observation.** $M_n(p) \le 1-H_2(p)$ for **every** $n$, where $H_2:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is the binary entropy function. See figure below.

[image]

> **Question.** Is there a simple proof for the above observation ?

Comment: This is true, see e.g. Lemma 3.6 in Robert M. Gray's book "Entropy and Information Theory".

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky Thanks for the input. Which edition of the book are you referring to ? I've managed to get hold of this free pdf version https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/it.pdf, but no Lemma 3.6. Also note the **non-asymptotic** (i.e **any** $n$) aspect of my question.

Comment: I should have specified. I refer to the second edition, available on google books, see page 74: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=wdSOqgVbdRcC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false. Gray does not give an attribution, but this result is certainly was known before the publication of the book.

Comment: Galvin provides a conceptual proof in Theorem 3.1 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7872 .

Comment: Great, thanks for the refs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments and references from user Ofir Gorodetsky, we can prove the following

> **Proposition.** $M_n(p) \le 1-H_2(p)$ for every positive integer $n$ and every $p \in (0,1/2)$.

*Proof.* As $p \in (0,1/2)$, we from [Theorem 3.1 of this tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7872.pdf) that

$$
S_n(p):= \sum_{1 \le i \le np}{n \choose i} \le 2^{nH_2(p)}.
$$

Thus, $M_n(p) := 1-(1/n)\log_2 S_n(p) \le 1-H_2(p)$, which concludes the proof.